# Python PyGame Restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

so i was learning python and i finished the game and everything is working but now i have no idea about how to restart the game i mean when it ends what is next? how to start again
i will put a [link](https://pastebin.com/CNVMBeZk) for my full code and here is what have done so far.

Thank you so much!

```
if Bullet_state is "fire":
        fire(BulletX, BulletY)
        BulletY -= Bullet_MovementY
    player(playerX, playerY)
    score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the restart logic, keep the current game loop but add a flag to indicate that the game has ended. In the loop, check for this flag and display the restart prompt if the flag is set. Also encapsulate the initialization process in a function so it can be called at each restart.

Note that I tested this in Python 3.8.

Try this code. When the score reaches 3, the game ends and the restart prompt is displayed.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invadors')
icon = pygame.image.load('1.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
#Background
Background = pygame.image.load('background.png')

def SetGameStart():    # initialize variables
    global Player_Image,playerX,playerY,Key_Movement,Enemy_Image,EnemyX,EnemyY,Enemy_MovementX,Enemy_MovementY
    global Bullet_Image,BulletX,BulletY,Bullet_MovementX,Bullet_MovementY,Bullet_state,Score
    # Player
    Player_Image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
    playerX = 370
    playerY = 480
    Key_Movement = 0
    # Enemy
    Enemy_Image = pygame.image.load('monster2.png')
    EnemyX = random.randint(0, 735)
    EnemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
    Enemy_MovementX = 1.5
    Enemy_MovementY = 40
    # Bullet
    Bullet_Image = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')
    BulletX = 0
    BulletY = 480
    Bullet_MovementX = 0
    Bullet_MovementY = 10
    Bullet_state = "Ready"

    Score = 0

def Fire(x, y):
    global Bullet_state
    Bullet_state = "Fire"
    screen.blit(Bullet_Image, (x + 16, y + 10))


def player(x, y):
    # blit is draw! draw an image on the screen
    screen.blit(Player_Image, (x, y))


def Enemy(x, y):
    screen.blit(Enemy_Image, (x, y))

def is_Collided(BulletX, BulletY, EnemyX, EnemyY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(BulletX - EnemyX, 2) + math.pow(BulletY - EnemyY, 2))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        

SetGameStart()  # initialize variables
GameDone = False

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, (0,200,0))
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

Close = True
while Close:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(Background, (0, 0))

    if GameDone:  # pause game loop, show restart prompt
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Game Over.    Press Space to restart.", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((800/2),(600/2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        pygame.display.update() 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               Close = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:  # press Q to quit
                Close = False
                break
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:  # press space to restart
                GameDone = False
                SetGameStart()  # initialize variables
        continue  # skip game process

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            Close = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                Key_Movement = -4
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Key_Movement = 4
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                # to fix the Pressing on space will reload the Bullet
                if Bullet_state is "Ready":
                    BulletX = playerX
                    Fire(BulletX, playerY)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                Key_Movement = 0
    playerX += Key_Movement
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:
        playerX = 736
    # Enemy movement limit
    EnemyX += Enemy_MovementX
    if EnemyX <= 0:
        Enemy_MovementX = 1.5
        EnemyY += Enemy_MovementY
    elif EnemyX >= 736:
        Enemy_MovementX = -1.5
        EnemyY += Enemy_MovementY
    if BulletY <= 0:
        BulletY = 480
        Bullet_state = "Ready"
    if Bullet_state is "Fire":
        Fire(BulletX, BulletY)
        BulletY -= Bullet_MovementY
    Collision = is_Collided(EnemyX, EnemyY, BulletX, BulletY)
    if Collision:
        BulletY = 480
        Bullet_state = "Ready"
        Score += 1
        print(Score)
        EnemyX = random.randint(0, 735)
        EnemyY = random.randint(50, 150)
    Enemy(EnemyX, EnemyY)
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update() 
    if Score == 3:
        GameDone = True
```

Prompt

[image: RestartGame]

Comment: Thank you so Much Mike 
can i ask for you tips about programming? i just started python and im kinda don't know what to do or how to be good and to understand and know what i need to do in general 
thank you once again :D